# Як правильно підгузник чи підгузок?

Tags: вибір-слова

Більшість сайтів з дитячим одягом вказує слово ***"підгузник"***

На сайті [Pampers](https://www.pampers.ua/products) скрізь вживається слово ***"підгузник"***

> Як правильно вибрати ***підгузник*** Pampers
>   ***Підгузники*** Pampers New Baby-Dry

В СУМ-11 надається визначення лише для слова 
***[ПІДГУ́ЗОК](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidghuzok)***

Як правильно підгузник чи підгузок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA/) знаходимо:

> Замініть нехарактерний для української мови іменник **підгузник** на правильний варіант: **підгузок.**

У [Орфографічному словнику](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA) та [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA) також знаходимо **підгузок**.

Згаданий Вами [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidghuzok) також підтверджує цю інформацію.

Отже, правильно вживати **підгузок.**

P.S.Знайшла досить цікаву інформацію про **підгузник** у [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53407/375463.html):

> ПІДГУЗНИК 
>   (-а) ч.; арм.; зневажл. Солдат строкової служби першого півроку служби. Балабін.